# iOS in-app purchase keeping track of items purchased

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am new to the world of in-app purchase and I just watched the tutorial on iTunes about how to integrate it to my app. I am wondering how the developer would keep track of the items purchased WITHOUT having to verify the receipt. I thinking it would be nice if we could just store the purchased items in the app because then we would be able to identify items purchased without having internet connection.

What's the convention to do this? Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad practice because, what happens when your user deletes and re-installs the app?
He won't have his purchased items anymore.

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) is a very good one, it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 way you can keep track of purchased items:

1 - **Storage** - Temporary / Permanent. Obviously Temporary storage doesn't protect you against deletion / device change. Permanent storage can be ensured if you store it in keychain or on your own server soon after purchase is successful.

2 - Apple's own API tells you - based on certain rules / condition.

**Condition**:  If this is non-consumable purchase, and you try to purchase again.([SKPaymentQueue addPayment])

The response from itunes store will cause storekit to invoke `updatedtransactions` - with status - `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`. This simply means that product is already purchased, needs to be restored - so it is your responsibility to unlock it.

In short, it won't allow you to purchase again if it's nonconsumable purchase. Same must be true for subscriptions that haven't yet expired (not sure about it).

If you need step by step tutorial on how to integrate IAP - here is [my own lecture series](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-ios-moneymaking-course-learn-in-app-purchases/?couponCode=PROMO29SO) with SWIFT and Objective C. It also accompanies code sample.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an app or device feature that is allowed or is capable of recording and managing EVERY in-app purchase made through the Apple ID.

Problem is… The current setup of in-app purchases is not user friendly.

In short: Buying is your problem and recording your purchases is only a "convenient feature provided generously" by Apple Inc and app developers.

It shouldn't be like this though. Apple Inc and the app developers should consolidate user purchase info and make it transparent and easy to access/understand by the user.

This is the 21st century, after all.